# Could this be converted to LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a reasonably long SQL query that I need to run in a .Net application. I can make it a stored procedure but I'd like to avoid it if possible (given that I may have a high number of queries in this app).

With this in mind, could something like the following be converted to LINQ or is it too detailed?

```
-- Compare current period to historical data
select  Name ,
        avg(TimeProcessing + TimeRendering + TimeDataRetrieval) / 1000  as 'Current Month' ,
        isnull(count(TimeProcessing), 0)                                as 'Sample' ,
        min(l2.[Avg_Exec_Time_Previous_Month])                          as 'Previous Month' ,
        isnull(min(l2.[Executions_Last_Month]), 0)                      as 'Sample' ,
        min(l3.[Avg_Exec_Time_Two_Months_Ago])                          as 'Two Months ago' ,
        isnull(min(l3.[Executions_Two_Months_Ago]), 0)                  as 'Sample'
from    marlin.report_execution_log l
        inner join marlin.report_catalog c on l.ReportID = c.ItemID
        left outer join ( 
                        select    
                            l2.ReportID ,
                            (
                            avg(l2.TimeProcessing + l2.TimeRendering 
                            + l2.TimeDataRetrieval) / 1000 
                            ) as 'Avg_Exec_Time_Previous_Month' ,
                            count(l2.TimeProcessing) as 'Executions_Last_Month'
                        from    
                            marlin.report_execution_log l2
                        where   
                            TimeEnd between dateadd(MONTH, -2, getdate())
                                    and     dateadd(MONTH, -1, getdate())
                        group by  
                            l2.ReportID
                        ) l2 on l.ReportID = l2.ReportID
        left outer join ( 
                        select    
                            l3.ReportID ,
                            (
                            avg(l3.TimeProcessing + l3.TimeRendering + l3.TimeDataRetrieval) / 1000 
                            ) as 'Avg_Exec_Time_Two_Months_Ago' ,
                            count(l3.TimeProcessing) as 'Executions_Two_Months_Ago'
                        from  
                            marlin.report_execution_log l3
                        where 
                            TimeEnd between dateadd(MONTH, -3, getdate())
                                    and     dateadd(MONTH, -2, getdate())
                        group by  
                            l3.ReportID
                        ) l3 on l.ReportID = l3.ReportID
group by    l.ReportID ,
            Name
order by    2 desc
```

Comment: Nothing makes me as sad as when I see that much calculation and logic in a stored procedure.

Comment: Are you asking to use some converter for it or ?

Comment: The answer is yes, you could convert it to Linq... But the question is whether it's worth it... Clearly, that proc is tough to maintain but if it works and in a mostly efficient manner, and if, as you said query performance is important, then you are very unlikely to improve that aspect of this code...

Comment: Why do you need to convert it to LINQ or a stored proc if it currently works? I'm not saying you shouldn't, just trying to understand the return for spending the time on this.

Comment: @hunter Definitely open to suggestions - still learning so I'd love any advice you can offer

Comment: @RalphWillgoss I thought LINQ would be the best way to deliver this in an application. I wrote the query in SSMS previously for an SSRS report. I can do this with a stored proc but wasn't sure if it was the best approach / was also curious about whether this could be a LINQ query

Comment: If you have a high number of queries, and have the sp already written, would that not be a reason for keeping it as a procedure? Or perhaps as a user-function since when you call user functions through Linq (I'm assuming you're using Linq elsewhere) you can make it part of a wider linq query to a greater extent than with stored procedures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are many tools /convertor are available on the internet. you can use this tools

- why not you try [Sql to Linq](http://www.sqltolinq.com/)
- [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/)